# Converting android file browser ListActivity example into a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter

I am trying to figure out a way to use this example in a fragment:
http://sampleprogramz.com/android/browse.php

I have changed the OnCreate method to the OnCreateView method and have tried to correct any of the errors that Android Studio flags but I can't seem to get it working.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

public class FilePicker extends ListFragment {

    public final static String EXTRA_FILE_PATH = "file_path";
    public final static String EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES = "show_hidden_files";
    public final static String EXTRA_ACCEPTED_FILE_EXTENSIONS = "accepted_file_extensions";
    private final static String DEFAULT_INITIAL_DIRECTORY = "/";

    protected File Directory;
    protected ArrayList<File> Files;
    protected FilePickerListAdapter Adapter;
    protected boolean ShowHiddenFiles = false;
    protected String[] acceptedFileExtensions;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_view, container, false);
        ((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);
        getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);

        // Set initial directory
        Directory = new File(DEFAULT_INITIAL_DIRECTORY);

        // Initialize the ArrayList
        Files = new ArrayList<File>();

        // Set the ListAdapter
        Adapter = new FilePickerListAdapter(getActivity(), Files);
        setListAdapter(Adapter);

        // Initialize the extensions array to allow any file extensions
        acceptedFileExtensions = new String[] {".rc"};

        // Get intent extras
        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_FILE_PATH))
            Directory = new File(getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_FILE_PATH));

        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES))
            ShowHiddenFiles = getActivity().getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_HIDDEN_FILES, false);

        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_ACCEPTED_FILE_EXTENSIONS)) {

            ArrayList<String> collection =
                    getActivity().getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_ACCEPTED_FILE_EXTENSIONS);

            acceptedFileExtensions = (String[])
                    collection.toArray(new String[collection.size()]);
        }
        return emptyView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        refreshFilesList();
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void refreshFilesList() {

        Files.clear();
        ExtensionFilenameFilter filter =
                new ExtensionFilenameFilter(acceptedFileExtensions);

        File[] files = Directory.listFiles(filter);

        if(files != null && files.length > 0) {

            for(File f : files) {

                if(f.isHidden() && !ShowHiddenFiles) {

                    continue;
                }

                Files.add(f);
            }

            Collections.sort(Files, new FileComparator());
        }

        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        File newFile = (File)l.getItemAtPosition(position);

        if(newFile.isFile()) {

            Intent extra = new Intent();
            extra.putExtra(EXTRA_FILE_PATH, newFile.getAbsolutePath());
            getActivity().setResult(RESULT_OK, extra);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
        else {

            Directory = newFile;
            refreshFilesList();
        }

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    private class FilePickerListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<File> {

        private List<File> mObjects;

        public FilePickerListAdapter(Context context, List<File> objects) {

            super(context, R.layout.list_item, android.R.id.text1, objects);
            mObjects = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View row = null;

            if(convertView == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                        getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }
            else
                row = convertView;

            File object = mObjects.get(position);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.file_picker_image);
            TextView textView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.file_picker_text);
            textView.setSingleLine(true);
            textView.setText(object.getName());

            if(object.isFile())
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound);

            else
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.folder);

            return row;
        }
    }

    private class FileComparator implements Comparator<File> {

        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {

            if(f1 == f2)
                return 0;

            if(f1.isDirectory() && f2.isFile())
                // Show directories above files
                return -1;

            if(f1.isFile() && f2.isDirectory())
                // Show files below directories
                return 1;

            // Sort the directories alphabetically
            return f1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(f2.getName());
        }
    }

    private class ExtensionFilenameFilter implements FilenameFilter {

        private String[] Extensions;

        public ExtensionFilenameFilter(String[] extensions) {

            super();
            Extensions = extensions;
        }

        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {

            if(new File(dir, filename).isDirectory()) {

                // Accept all directory names
                return true;
            }

            if(Extensions != null && Extensions.length > 0) {

                for(int i = 0; i < Extensions.length; i++) {

                    if(filename.endsWith(Extensions[i])) {

                        // The filename ends with the extension
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                // The filename did not match any of the extensions
                return false;
            }
            // No extensions has been set. Accept all file extensions.
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Post your error code

Comment: Replace setContentView with LayoutInflater.inflate + return that view  and you're halfway there...

Comment: What's in your logcat? Why are you returning an empty view?

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to android, I'm guessing the empty view is there by default if no files are found?

Comment: The logcat says:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.browse/com.browse.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewParent android.widget.AdapterView.getParent()'

and

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewParent android.widget.AdapterView.getParent()' on a null object reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by inflating a new xml layout for the filepicker fragment,

I replaced:

```
View emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_view, container, false);
    ((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);
    getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);

    // Set initial directory
    Directory = new File(DEFAULT_INITIAL_DIRECTORY);

    // Initialize the ArrayList
    Files = new ArrayList<File>();

    // Set the ListAdapter
    Adapter = new FilePickerListAdapter(getActivity(), Files);
    setListAdapter(Adapter);
```

With:

```
View viewlist = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_picker, container, false);       
lv = (ListView) viewlist.findViewById(R.id.filebrowselist);

    // Set initial directory
    Directory = new File(String.valueOf(DEFAULT_INITIAL_DIRECTORY));

    // Initialize the ArrayList
    Files = new ArrayList<File>();


    // Set the ListAdapter
    Adapter = new FilePickerListAdapter(getActivity(), Files);
    lv.setAdapter(Adapter);
```